# Recognize touches using touches began on any superview

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a custom view that contains a UITextField

[image]

I've made the delegate for the UITextView the custom view, in order to encapsulate behaviours about the view to its own file. I then use touches began to close the keyboard when someone touches the screen

```
@IBDesignable
class NewPostView:UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var newPostTextView: UITextView!

    func setup() {
    ...
        newPostTextView.delegate = self
    }
...

    /* Closes the keyboard when somewhere else on the screen is touched */
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
        closeKeyboard()
    }
```

This only closes the keyboard when the view is custom view is touched however. I'm wondering what the best way to go about closing the text field would be when the screen is touched anywhere, considering that I would still like to encapsulate the custom view as much as possible.

---

I don't know how to assign the delegate to the view controller. I've tried `newPostTextView.delegate = self.superview()` but this attaches it to the superview and not the view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view only intercepts touches in its area.

You need to either setup the touchesBegan on the parent view (or the view that covers the screen space in question), or I'd suggest using a tapGestureRecognizer. It encapsulates things a little better IMO.

Comment: How would I assign the delegate? I've tried attaching the delegate to the superview but don't know how I would attach it to the view controller

Comment: Are you using storyboards? Just drop a UITapGesture object on the view in question, then assign the IBOutlet to your swift class.